# getting a list of images from local folder

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm writing a C# UWP app that displays images from a user's photo library. I would like to see how I can get all the photos and display each one in a GridViewItem and flipviewitem.

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pictureQueryOptions = new QueryOptions();
    //Read through all the subfolders. 
    pictureQueryOptions.FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep;
    //Apply the query on the PicturesLibrary 
    var pictureQuery = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(pictureQueryOptions);
    // 
    var picturesInformation = new FileInformationFactory(pictureQuery, ThumbnailMode.PicturesView);
    picturesSource.Source = picturesInformation.GetVirtualizedFilesVector();
}
```

and

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var img = (IRandomAccessStream)value;
            var picture = new BitmapImage();
            picture.SetSource(img);
            return picture;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }          

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please read about [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: I got the code, but How do I bind the actual image? I get the image to display, but it's just a thumbnail. How can I get the actual file?

Comment: @TylerS Please post your code, what have you tried and what is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest fix for your code would be to increase the size of thumbnails (they can get up to 1024px, so it should be enough) using this constructor:

```
FileInformationFactory.FileInformationFactory(IStorageQueryResultBase, ThumbnailMode, UInt32, ThumbnailOptions)
```

Other than that, you can set BitmapImage from StorageFile like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc9aa758-f211-468b-8168-a671b7a0c8b4/uwp-creating-bitmapimage-with-uri-accessing-file-from-same-uri-gives-exception?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: This seems to have worked. The only thing that doesn't display correctly are portrait images. Thanks! :)

Comment: @TylerS you don't say thanks here, it is not according to the rules - you should upvote and mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

you can get  user photo library from

```
var myPictures = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Pictures);
```

loop through all images from this folder

update Package.appxmanifest

```
<Capabilities>
<uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
```

Comment: I added that, but how do I bind the images? I tried `PictureSource.Source = myPictures but the app broke